# Only call function if another function is ready

Tags: objective-c, ios, function

How can i make sure in Objective-C, that a function only get called, until another function is ready?

**Update:**

```
-(void)reloadJsonFromServer {
    [[Sync sharedObject] synchronise];
    [self reload];
}
```

I've got this function.
The second function "reload" should only be called, if the first function is – in this case it's a singlton – is ready. Ready means, that the first function is no more longer running.

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be ready?

Comment: You need to provide much more info here.

Comment: You're right. I've added some more information.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to wait on the completion of an asynchronous method? There's a whole bunch of ways to do that.

- Make the `synchronise` method itself call `reload` on your object when it finishes
- `dispatch_async` the `reload` method and have it just `wait` until the other method populates some flag or data structure that you are waiting on before continuing (`BOOL synchronised` or similar). Note that if your `reload` method does anything with `UIKit`, though, then you need to run it on the main thread.
- Change the way `synchronise` runs so it doesn't actually return to the caller until it's done synchronising, but then `dispatch_async` the `reloadJsonFromServer` method.
- Change `synchronise` as in the third point, but instead of using `dispatch_async`, add both of the method calls to an `NSOperationQueue` as `NSOperation`s, with `reload` dependent on the completion of `synchronise`. The operation queue will handle it after that.

Those are just a few, I'm sure other people can suggest more.

Comment: Yes, i want to wait on an asynchronous method, right. The problem is, that "synchronise" calls some other functions in the Sync class. When i want to embed a callback function, i get the same problem, that the "reload" function will be called before the other functions in the Sync class are ready. Is your second point something like eventlistening? You wrote about flags.

Comment: Yes, the second point is waiting for a value to be set (an event processing flag or something) before the `reload` method continues doing what it should. You `dispatch_async` so that the interface can still update and the main run loop continues while synchronisation is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the last few days, i've learnd something about notifications.
I think that is a good way too, to handle something like this. For more information about this look at this blog entry.

[Custom Events in Objective-C](http://www.rwichmann.com/2009/03/02/custom-events-in-objective-c/)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but with NSNotification it can be handled.

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[center addObserverForName:nil
                    object:nil
                     queue:nil
                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
{
     NSLog(@"%@", notification.name);
}];
```

Look at this: http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/